# How do I get a value from a key-value pair in an object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am writing an asp.net application that I set up to communicate to a company's software via xml-rpc.  This aspect is working, and I am receiving the data correctly, I'm just not sure how to access that data in the object I read it into.  When I set a breakpoint and mouse over the object in VS I can see the data correctly in the tooltip, just not sure how to access it programmatically. The data is located as shown in the attached picture.

[image]

Comment: Into what data type are you reading the data? Is `returnValue` what you are reading into?

Comment: Yes. I am reading it into returnValue, the tooltip kinda covered that up.

Comment: When you hit your break point, go into the immediate window (Debug, Windows, Immediate) and type `? returnValue.GetType().Name` what do you get?

Comment: This command returns "Object[]"

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to determine then type of key value pair you're dealing with and how far it's nested. Try `? returnValue(1).GetType().Name` to get the type of the second element. It seems from your screenshot this is the key value pair

Comment: This returns exactly the same, "Object[]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147643/discussion-between-fabulous-and-jonw).

Comment: ok im in the chat

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the following line of code:

```
DirectCast((DirectCast((DirectCast(returnValue, Object())(1)), Object())(0)), XmlRpcStruct).Values(0).ToString
```